# iphone X navigation display issue

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have two items on the navigation bar. named More on the left and Search on the right. When i run the app on the simulator, two items are moved to 2 top ears of the phone. see below for more detail. this is not happening on none iphone X
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your constraints are set to `superview`, not `safe area` (or not using safe area at all).

In your `Storyboard`, click on your `ViewController`, click on your `view` then go to the `Size inspector`.

There, make sure that your `safe area layout guide` is enabled. Then, just bind your view's edges to `safe area` instead of `superview`

[image]